# How to remove the Old Reply Data from Incoming Email

Tags: java, smtp, jakarta-mail, imap

I am using java mail API for fetching incoming mails from the mail box , now facing a problem when one mail revived as a  reply then it includes old mail data also how can i extract the mail content ,is there any specific flag or way for solving this issue.

Comment: May I assume the original mail is included in the received one ? If you, unless parsing, you can't do much. More, can you give an example of what you received, what have you tried.

Comment: @MasterDJon for an activity system will send a mail to user ,user can replay back to that mail id ,but in replay includes what the mail send already.my problem is how to remove the previous one

Comment: There was a typo error in my last comment, you should have read *If yes*.  So here is the round-trip I presume you do : SMTP -> POP3 -> SMTP. Can you confirm that ? Please ensure to be precise and edit your question instead (so others won't have to read those comments unless they want to) and add a comment saying : "@MasterDJon question edited".

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to detect or remove the "reply" data from a message because there's no standard for how the original message is included in a reply message.  If you know something about the mailers that will be used, you can predict how the original message will be included in the reply and you can write some string processing logic to find it and remove it.  If you have to support all possible mailers, you're stuck with a bunch of heuristics that are going to fail sometimes.

Comment: Shannnon how there mail clients like Thunderbird and all identifying ,they hide the previous contents

Comment: They're full of those heuristics.  They don't work in all cases.